# Writing list view items into internal storage

Tags: java, android

I'm using an application to find SSID and displaying them using a listView . Is there a way to write the data found in the listView into the internal storage on the phone?

```
private void scanWifi() {
    arrayList.clear();
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifiManager.startScan();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning WiFi ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

---

```
BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        unregisterReceiver(this);

        for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
            arrayList.add(scanResult.SSID + " - " + scanResult.capabilities);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

Manifest Page with all the permissions used for the program

```
    <uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
     android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)